# Is is possible to get programmatically get the EC2 instance types that support AMX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Only certain EC2 instance type families like [m7i](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m7i/), [m7i-flex](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m7i/) and [r7i](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/r7i/) support [AMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Matrix_Extensions) (Advanced Matrix Extensions).

Is there any way to obtain the list of instance types that support [AMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Matrix_Extensions) programatically via the AWS API?

I've tried with the [DescribeInstanceTypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypes.html) but I don't see it in [InstanceTypeInfo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceTypeInfo.html) or [ProcessorInfo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ProcessorInfo.html), the only thing exposed seems to be if `amd-sev-snp` is supported or not.

But I wonder if there is any other way to get it via the API, or some list published somewhere (preferably in a computer-readable way).